# How to access the elements inside wpf datagrid column header template?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, wpfdatagrid

How to access the elements inside  wpf datagrid column header template through code?

there is a solution,but i couldn't make it work.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3237cb62-3a6a-4663-9f1e-7894cb24c674

actually i don't know whats

> Control.nameproperty

and

> Header

in the answer above?

Answer (score 1):

For people who are still having this problem.

You have this template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel x:Name="DockPanelFilter"></DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            <Image x:Name="ImageLock" Source="Resources/lock.png" Width="14" Height="14" Margin="2,0,0,0"></Image>
        </StackPanel>    
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and you want to access the ImageLock image.
You could use:

```
Public Shared BooAfterItemsPresenter As Boolean = False
Public Shared ColumnName As String = String.Empty
Public Shared Function FindVisualChildByName(Of T As DependencyObject)(parent As DependencyObject, name As String, columnNameI As String) As T
    Dim ColumnNameInput As String = columnNameI
    For i As Integer = 0 To VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent) - 1
        Dim child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i)
        Dim controlName As String = TryCast(child.GetValue(Control.NameProperty), String)
        If TypeName(child) = "DataGridCellsPanel" Then
            BooAfterItemsPresenter = True
        End If
        If BooAfterItemsPresenter = True AndAlso TypeName(child) = "DataGridColumnHeader" Then
            Dim DGColHeader = CType(child, DataGridColumnHeader)
            If DGColHeader.Content IsNot Nothing Then
                ColumnName = DGColHeader.Content.ToString
            Else
                ColumnName = ""
            End If
        End If
        If controlName = name AndAlso ColumnName = ColumnNameInput Then
            Return TryCast(child, T)
        Else
            Dim result As T = FindVisualChildByName(Of T)(child, name, ColumnNameInput)
            If result IsNot Nothing Then
                Return result
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

and then when you use this function:

```
Public Sub hideImageLock ()
        Dim ImageLock = FindVisualChildByName(Of Image)(dataGrid, "ImageLock", "NEU2")
        ImageLock.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub
```

I hope that it helps some people!

[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) [vb](/questions/tagged/vb)

Answer (score 0):

Name property is the name you give to that Control.

in xaml you specify it by x:Name or simply by Name property of that control like below . This mean you are creating an object of TextBox class whose name is TextBox1.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"/>
<TextBox Name="TextBox2"/>
```

in code behind it is the name of object

```
TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
```

Similarly Header is property of DataGridColumn.

I hope this will help.